# How to create an alias correctly

Tags: awk, alias, bash

I've tested this command

```
$ nmap -sP 192.168.1.* | grep 192  | awk '{print $5}'
```

which produces this output

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.33
192.168.1.34
192.168.1.36
192.168.1.41
```

And then added it to my .bash_alias file and then sourced it.

```
# This alias shows IPs on the local network
alias list-ip="nmap -sP 192.168.1.* | grep 192  | awk '{print $5}'"
```

But then it produces this output

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.1
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.33
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.34
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.36
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.41
```

I've got no clue on what I'm doing whrong. I just want the output to be like when I run it on command-line, and it should be.

Comment: I don't think the name `list-ip` is ok, can you try avoiding `-` with something like `list_ip`?

Comment: @fedorqui No, in `bash` dashes are fine in function/alias names.

Comment: Uhms, good to know, @AdrianFrühwirth, I thougt not. Thanks!

Comment: `grep | awk` is never needed just do  `nmap -sP 192.168.1.* | awk '/192/{print $5}'`

Comment: Also, you should probably use ``^192\.` as your regex.

Comment: @tripleee I think you misread the question. `nmap`'s output looks like `Nmap scan report for XYZ`, so `^192` won't match anything.

Comment: Right, still maybe keep the dot, and/or anchor the match to a field, like `$5 ~ /^192\./ { ... }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use double quotes, so `$5` gets expanded at the time you set the alias. Try

```
 alias list-ip="nmap -sP 192.168.1.* | grep 192  | awk '{print \$5}'"
```

Note that

```
 alias list-ip='nmap -sP 192.168.1.* | grep 192  | awk "{print $5}"'
```

will *not* work because the expansion still takes place, this time when you run the alias.

You can also get rid of the `awk`, e.g.:

```
 alias list-ip='nmap -sP 192.168.1.* | grep -o "192[0-9.]*"'
```

Comment: the regex option sounds great!

Comment: or get rid of the grep and then your solution will work even when you don't have GNU grep available and, probably more importantly, it will not find false-matches if "192" appears elsewhere in nmap output: `alias list-ip="nmap -sP 192.168.1.* | awk '\$5~/^192\./{print \$5}'".

Comment: @EdMorton I totally agree that it is better not to rely on GNU `grep`, but I disagree about the false positives since if `nmap` is able to reverse-resolve the IP its output looks differently (e.g. `Nmap scan report for mybox (192.168.x.y)`) in which case the 5th column is not what you want. You can change the `awk` to account for that, but I think this is more readable and also more robust if its output is in another language (which I believe it supports).

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth - I have no idea what "nmap" is, all I have to go on is the sample output the OP posted but he didn't post what the input to the grep/awk looked like so it's guess-work on my part how to write the grep/awk to parse it. My concern is that if "nmap" can produce output that contains "168.192.x.y" then the grep command will falsely match it (assuming the OP just wants IP addresses that start with 192).